# Is there a $k$-algebra with finitely many primes and which is algebra-finite but not module-finite, over $k$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is there a field $k$ and a (commutative associative unital) $k$-algebra $A$ such that:

1. $A$ has finitely many distinct prime ideals; and
2. $A$ is finitely generated as a $k$-algebra; and
3. $A$ is *not* finitely generated as a $k$-module?

I'm wondering if we take $k$ a finite field, then does $A = k[x,y]/(xy)$ give such an example? This certainly satisfies 2 and 3; and there are finitely many "$k$-points" of the curve $xy=0$ simply due to $k$ being finite; however I'm not sure if $A$ actually has finitely many prime ideals.

Comment: This is impossible by the *Noether normalization theorem*: there is a finite injective map $R:=k[x_1,\ldots,x_r] \rightarrow A$. As $A$ is not finite over $k$, $r>0$. If $p \subset R$ is a prime ideal, then $R_p \rightarrow A_p$ is finite injective, and a maximal ideal $m$ of $A_p$ is a prime ideal of $A$ above $p$. Thus $\operatorname{Spec}{A} \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}{R}$ is onto, and in particular $A$ has infinitely many prime ideals.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2892962/finitely-generated-k-algebra-of-krull-dimension-one-has-infinitely-many-primes .

Comment: @Aphelli I see, thanks so much for your help!